C# MySQL Error: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Expected end of data packet
I am having the weirdest issue with MySQL and my C# web application...
Whenever I call this method without the PrepareAsync(), then it returns my data perfectly fine.
However when I do use the PrepareAsync() method, it gives me a MySQL Exception:

MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Expected end of
data packet

public async Task Test()
{
    using MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connection);
    conn.Open();
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM characters WHERE deleted=0 ORDER BY @columnName DESC", conn);
    await cmd.PrepareAsync(); // <--------------- HERE
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@columnName", "alchemyXP");
    using var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();

    while (await reader.ReadAsync())
    {
        var v = reader["alchemyXP"];
        var vv = reader["name"];
    }
}

My MySQL Server version is: 8.0.32
My MySQL Server + all tables are charset: utf8mb4
My MySQL.Data NuGet package is: 8.3.0
My MySQL connection string in the application is:

server=10.0.0.12;uid=test123;pwd=pass123;database=testdb123;CharSet=utf8mb4;


Check this thread https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector/issues/397
Connector/NET has a IgnorePrepare connection string setting that defaults to true; unless the user explicitly sets that to false then its Prepare method also does nothing.

Try to add parameters first and then call prepare. also, AddWithValue is not very good option. Do cmd.Parameters.Add( with concrete data type

lets start with MySql.Data.MySqlClient can have many bugs some of which I have reported   https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=92912

According to 12.3.2 Server Character Set and Collation: MySQL Server has a server character set and a server collation. By default, these are utf8mb4 and utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci. The following may also be of interest: 12.3.8 Character Set Introducers and 12.4 Connection Character Sets and Collations

You may try removing CharSet=utf8mb4; from your connection string and also use Add (as shown here) instead of AddWithValue even though 6.1.4 Working with Parameters seems to use AddWithValue.

Looks like client-side bug. Similar to the following issue https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=92912. Maybe try alternative connector https://mysqlconnector.net/ to confirm.

@T.S. MySql.Data changed the default value of IgnorePrepare to false in v8.0.23: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/connector-net/en/news-8-0-23.html. Since then, Prepare (and PrepareAsync) have had an effect.

You can't parameterize column names in a SQL statement. ORDER BY @columnName will become ORDER BY 'alchemyXP' when the parameter is bound, which is just ordering by a constant, ignoring the data in the table. You will have to build this "dynamic" statement with string concatenation, whether or not you prepare the MySqlCommand.

Bradley Grainger's comment was the correct solution for my issue:

You can't parameterize column names in a SQL statement. ORDER BY @columnName will become ORDER BY 'alchemyXP' when the parameter is bound, which is just ordering by a constant, ignoring the data in the table. You will have to build this "dynamic" statement with string concatenation, whether or not you prepare the MySqlCommand.

